# serializer.save() not saving data to admin database

Tags: django, reactjs

So, i was making a simple Web app in which i would get in data from user using React JS Front-end Interface and Forms. Django stays in the background where i have made CRUD functions.

My app lets user to create, edit, delete and view the data inputted.

Edit and View work perfectly fine but create has been making a problem for me. There is no error in the browser console or django terminal but the React JS front-end change does not reflect in the Django Admin.

Now, handleChange simply listens to the change made in the HTML form. Active Record is my current form in which new data is being added:

```
handleChange(e){
var value = e.target.value;
this.setState({ 
activeRecord:{ 
   ...this.state.activeRecord, 
   [e.target.name]:value
```

} }) }

handleSubmit() just connects my frontend submit button to Django's CRUD'S Create url. Finally, i set the current object state back to default.

```
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('Item',this.state.activeRecord)

    var csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken')
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/DataCollection/create/'


    fetch(url,{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(this.state.activeRecord)
    })  .then((response)=>{
            this.fetchTasks()
            this.setState({
                activeRecord:{
                    id: "",
                    full_name:"",
                    age:"",
                    gender:"",
                    weight:"",
                    height:"",
                    salary: "",
                    project_count: "",
                    job_domain: "",
                    experience: "",
                    no_of_jobs:"",
                }
            })
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log('ERROR',error)
      })

}
```

handleSubmit() just connects my frontend submit button to Django's CRUD'S Create url.

Please note that there is no error shown when i run it but 2nd line console.log in the handlSubmit() function shows the inputted values implying that my added data is reaching react js at least.

Thus, this makes me think there is some issue with the Django part and hence, i have posted this question in this subreddit.

Note: I am an aspiring data scientist who is to start his Master Studies in September 2020. Just wanted to add some Web App Development skills to my resume.

Any suggestion would be appreciated....

Create View:

```
 @api_view(['POST'])
  def createRecord(request):
  serializer = InputValuesSerializers(data=request.data)
  if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

b.) Serializer: serializers.ModelSerializer had to be this way. Got a gruesome error when i tried to use serializers.Serializer

class InputValuesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = InputValues
fields = '**all**'

I've tried all the online resources and discussions but cannot find the solution. This is really frustrating as i can that the data is going where it's supposed to go, but only a single statement might me screwing things up.

I would really appreciate any help over this.

Comment: Just a silly question, are you sure that the code goes into the `if` statement body? I mean does calling `serializer.is_valid()` return `True` in your case?

Comment: Yup. I print print(serializer.data) inside the if body. It printed out the data i inputted via my browser. This bug is really trying me out...